# How to recover all data if OS changes from windows to raspbian?

Tags: windows, raspbian, data-recovery

I've installed Raspbian OS in my PC ,so all my data in  windows 10 drives is may be deleted . Do I recover that ?  (in a very critical situation)

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you didn't wipe the disk. I also assume that you stopped using your disk immediately to avoid overwriting your files.

Teskdisk will not work for you. But scalpel will. I will explain two ways to use it, depending your sources and your tools.

First, I assume that you have another laptop/desktop with a linux OS and a SATA to USB converter. If these apply to you, for faster results, do the following.

1. Extract the disk from your PC
2. Connect it via USB to another PC
3. Install the package scalpel
4. With your favourite editor (vi/vim/nano, etc) open the file /etc/scalpel/scalpel.conf and uncomment the preferred lines
5. Run the following command ( scalpel /dev/sdX# -o output ) which will scan your disk and find any selected file type that is not overwritten but it may find some corrupted files.

Secondly, I assume that you have a USB disk with a linux iso. This way is cheaper but slower. In that case, do the following.

1. Boot from the USB to the linux OS
2. Install the package scalpel
3. With your favourite editor (vi/vim/nano, etc) open the file /etc/scalpel/scalpel.conf and uncomment the preferred lines
4. Run the following command ( scalpel /dev/sdX# -o output ) which will scan your disk and find any selected file type that is not overwritten but it may find some corrupted files.

The folder named output will be in the path from which you ran the command scalpel. In the folder named output will be a  txt file named audit.txt and folders with the selected types you searched for and inside them the recovered files, many of which will be corrupted.

Wish you luck!